# textView.toString() return usual string android

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I have this fragment contains, textView (currentName), EditText (editNewName) and a button (updateNewName) which allows me to change the name.
My problem when log those two to see the result of toString(). Here is what I've got:

```
08-27 20:14:02.121  22707-22707/com.example.harounsmida.slidingmenu I/New Name﹕ [ 08-27 20:14:02.121  1800: 2398 V/audio_policy_anm ]
audio_io_handle_t android::ap_get_output(audio_policy*, audio_stream_type_t, uint32_t, audio_format_t, uint32_t, audio_output_flags_t): tid 2398
08-27 20:14:02.121  22707-22707/com.example.harounsmida.slidingmenu I/Current Name﹕ android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{420da9f8 V.ED.... ........ 0,129-122,170 #7f0d006f app:id/current_name}
```

Here is My fragment class:

```
public class ChangeNameFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView currentName;
private EditText editNewName;
private Button updateNewName;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

public ChangeNameFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_name, container, false);

    currentName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_name);
    editNewName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_new_name);
    updateNewName = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.update_new_name);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setTitle("Updating profile..");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    currentName.setText(db.getUserDetails().get("name"));
    updateNewName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newName = editNewName.getText().toString();
            Log.i("New Name ",newName);
            Log.i("Current Name ",currentName.toString());
            if (newName.isEmpty() || newName.matches(currentName.toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please enter new name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                pDialog.show();
                changeName(newName);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

I don't know where is the problem because I've been doing like always and this is the first time I see this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `toString()` on a `TextView`. To get the text from it, you need to do this

```
Log.i("Current Name ",currentName.getText().toString());
```

the same way that you get the text from your `EditText`

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't notice that one, but in EditText case it's correct, By the way that log came after I left EditText empty, but as far i know, if EditText is empty, so will be newName, no?

Comment: Correct. If the `EditText` is empty, `editNewName.getText().toString()` will return an empty string, i.e. `""`

Comment: But that's not my case as you can see in the log

Comment: The `String` object itself is indeed empty, but when you Log it, it spits out some extra information. I'm not sure exactly why it does this, but it's the expected behavior. If you use the `String` later on, it will be the correct value

Comment: Here is an in depth look at why Logcat does this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32145432/2278598

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
currentName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.current_name);
editNewName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_new_name);
updateNewName = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.update_new_name);
String newName = editNewName.getText().toString();

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
pDialog.setTitle("Updating profile..");
pDialog.setCancelable(false);

db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

currentName.setText(db.getUserDetails().get("name"));
updateNewName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.i("New Name ",newName);
        Log.i("Current Name ",currentName.getText().toString());
        if (newName.isEmpty() || newName.matches(currentName.toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please enter new name.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            pDialog.show();
            changeName(newName);
        }
    }
});
```